# Can ANT change values in a XML files?

Tags: java, spring, ant

Can ANT change values in a XML files?

I am working on a Java, Spring system and in the XML files we have things like server name, user name, password that has to change for each env that we are promoting the system too.  I would like to have the ANT script ask prompt the SA for the server name, user name and then replace the values in the xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also look into loading the properties in your Spring xml file from a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurator.  Then, you can keep your properties in a standard Java .properties file and edit that however you want when promoting your project through the tiers.  There's a halfway decent example here: [example](http://www.zparacha.com/how-to-read-properties-file-in-spring/#.T6PWlL_kXqc)

Comment: this is great for the Spring code but how about for my Log4j.xml file changes.

Comment: Ah, so it's more than Spring.  I'll add a +1 for the XmlTask answer in that case.  I've used that one as well with some success.  I'll add that xmltask also lets you predefine blocks of XML and reference them by ID, so you might be able to build up a collection of XML chunks relevant to each tier, then reference the one you want a deployment for.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have placeholders like @someProperty@ and do a straight search and replace but you can use [XmlTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/). We use it to change the context root for EARs - it's not very pretty due to the XML namespace nonsense:

```
<xmltask source="META-INF/application.xml"  report="true" failwithoutmatch="true" dest="META-INF/application.xml">
     <replace path="//*[local-name()='application']//*[local-name()='module'][@id='WebModule_XXXX']//*[local-name()='web']//*[local-name()='context-root']/text()" withText="${contextRoot}"/>
</xmltask>
```

But to change things like what you want we now use Spring 3.1 profiles and all we do is switch the environment profile in a property file. We have separate profiles for development, automated-uat, qa & production.

Comment: Maybe not pretty but more robust than my suggestion, so +1

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Ant replace task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) for string substitution, just pick suitable strings for your placeholders.

The [input task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html) can be used to harvest the required values.

Comment: Could also use the copy task with filtering

Answer (score 0):

You can use ant filter as indicated by Guillaume Polet comment. I followed the same and it solved my problem. Refer https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/filter.html for more details.